# Ansible not finding custom python modules on remote server

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to call a python function from another script in a different directory. Have a playbook to execute this.

This works fine on localhost but on remote_server it is failing with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'"

## Here are my scripts:

```
[root@server Test]# ls
hosts  playbook  python1  python2
```

```
[root@server Test]# cat playbook/playbook.yml 

- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:

    - name: Connect to MongoDB
      script: ../python1/script1.py
      args:
        executable: python3
```

```py
[root@server Test]# cat python1/script1.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

sys.path.append("../python2")

from script2 import dbServer


def main():

    cursor = dbServer()
    print(cursor.count())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```py
[root@server Test]# cat python2/script2.py 

#! /usr/bin/python

from pymongo import MongoClient

def connectToMongoDB():

    global db

    try:
        conn = MongoClient("myserver.com")
        db = conn.CMDB
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nUnable to fetch details from MongoDB..!!!\n%s\n" % e)
        sys.exit()


def dbServer():

    connectToMongoDB()

    collection = db.dbServer
    cursor = collection.find()

    return cursor
```

## Execution:

```
[root@server playbook]# ansible-playbook -i ../hosts playbook.yml -e "host=localhost"

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Connect to MongoDB] *******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
[root@server playbook]# ansible-playbook -i ../hosts playbook.yml -e "host=myremote"

PLAY [remote_server] ************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [myremote]

TASK [check ping status of P10 systems] *****************************************************************************
fatal: [myremote]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return
code", "rc": 1, "stderr": "Shared connection to myremote closed.\r\n",
"stderr_lines": ["Shared connection to myremote closed."], "stdout":
"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File
\"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1602453181.740341-
25196530470896/script1.py\", line 8, in <module>\r\n    from script2
import dbServer\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'\r\n",
"stdout_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File
\"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1602453181.740341-
25196530470896/script1.py\", line 8, in <module>", "    from script2
import dbServer", "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'script2'"]}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
myremote : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Please help how can I get my module copied to remote server. I need to get this working in AWX as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in module `script` document : *The local script at path will be transferred to the remote node and then executed*.

Any imported files in script will not, you must copy them before on remote with module `copy`.

Example (adapt access modes and path if needed) :

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes

  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3

  tasks:
    - name: Create directory
      copy:
        path: /tmp/python1
        state: directory
        mode: 0755
    - name: Copy scripts
      copy:
        src: ../python1
        dest: /tmp/python1

    - name: Connect to MongoDB
      script: ../python1/script1.py
      args:
        chdir: /tmp/python1
        executable: python3
```

However, it is usually preferable to write Ansible modules rather than pushing scripts.

Your script works locally because all needed imported files already exists

Comment: Thank you so much! This resolved my issue.

What do you mean by "it is usually preferable to write Ansible modules rather than pushing scripts."
How can I do that in my case?